# numbering of \paragraph command

Tags: sections-paragraphs

Due to the limitations of the number of subsubsections, subsubsubsections that we can use, I notice that I could replace that with the command \paragraph. Now when I use that, I am amazed by its function and would like to consult two things:

1. In my first `\paragraph` command of `Chapter 2, section 2.2`, the numbering appear as `2.2.0.1`. May I know if it is possible to change it to `2.2.1`? If it is possible, may I know how it can be done?
2. I notice `\paragraph` command doesn't add the heading to the table of contents. May I know how to incorporate the `Title 1` from `\paragraph{Title 1}` into the table of contents?

Thank You.

Comment: The command `\paragraph` is semantically speaking *below* `\subsubsection`, so if you skip the latter its number is still at 0. Second, to get paragraph-level (and subparagraph-level) entries to show up in the TOC, issue the instruction `\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}`

Comment: @Mico Please make this an answer. I was about to say the same when I saw your comment.

Comment: @Christian: Done! :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The command `\paragraph` is, semantically speaking, *subordinated* to the `\subsubsection` command. Each time a LaTeX sectioning command is used, two things happen (*inter alia*): First, the counter associated with its level -- `part`, `chapter`, `section`, `subsection`, `subsubsection`, `paragraph`, and `subparagraph` -- is incremented by 1; second, the counters of all subordinated sectioning levels are reset to 0. (Just for completeness, I should note that there's an exception to this rule: the `\part` command does *not* reset the `chapter` counter.)

Why does this matter for your document? Well, in most "standard" LaTeX document classes --such as `article`, `report`, and `book` -- the default style is to display the sectioning header's "number" as a composite of the counters of the current sectioning level and all higher level sectioning groupings (except, usually, the `part` level). So what happens when LaTeX encounters a sequence of commands such as

```
\section{Big ideas}
\subsection{Preliminaries}
\paragraph{Exciting details}
```

Because no `\subsubsection` command is provided in this example between `\subsection` and `\paragraph`, the counter for the `subsubsection` level is still at 0, and the other counters will be at 1. Therefore, when LaTeX processes the `\paragraph` command, its header will be constructed as

```
1.1.0.1 Exciting details
```

Moral of the story: Don't skip higher-level sectioning commands when using lower-level sectioning commands such as `\paragraph` or `\subparagraph`.

---

Regarding your second question, on how to get `paragraph`-level headers displayed in the Table of Contents (ToC). LaTeX has a parameter called `tocdepth`, which controls the depth of sectioning levels that will be shown in the ToC. Most document classes I'm familiar with set this parameter to `3`, which means that only sectioning commands up to and including `subsubsection` will be shown (but not `paragraph` and `subparagraph`, because their associated sectioning levels are set at `4` and `5`, respectively). To get `paragraph` and `subparagraph` headers to be listed in the ToC, just set

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
```

in the document's preamble. Happy TeXing!

Comment: Thus, if one does not like the default design of subsubsections and would like to use numbered paragraphs instead, one would have to overwrite the definitions? Any quick answers for how to achieve that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @D.Duesen - Please post a *new query* to raise these points. That way, lot's more people will see it and get a chance to provide an answer.